# Sending commands to application via JSON call

Tags: java, json

I wrote a java application that is supposed to run on a server in the background 24/7. I would like implement a possibility to communicate a change of parameters to this application over the internet. The easiest way that came to my mind was if the application would just get parameters via a JSON call. It checks this JSON every now and then and thereby "retrieves" new commands, instead of "receiving" them.

To realize this I was looking for a simple way to create and edit a JSON online that can be called by a single URL. I have found http://www.json-generator.com/ but unfortunately it doesn't let me edit an existing JSON.

Does anyone know a solution for this? Or does anyone know a simpler way to communicate with your application over the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: So what you're looking for is some sort of JSON editor utility, possibly one that runs as a web page?

Comment: Yes exactly. It doesn't have to be a JSON format, this was just the simplest form of passing text that came to my mind.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know how you understood the requirements, but my head is hurting..

Comment: Just a suggestion. Wouldn't it be easier to read xml instead?

Comment: @TejaswiRana - JSON is a lot easier to write and read than is XML.

Comment: @TejaswiRana XML, easier than JSON? The JSON RFC (RFC 7159) is 12 pages long (reference links included) and describes JSON fully

Comment: If your command POJO is simple and understood at the other end, you can use a JSON {de,}serialization library (such as Jackson), serialize on the client, send to the server, deserialize on the server. Also note the existence of JSON-RPC for which Java libraries exist

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe it's not the most correct and beautiful way to achieve your goal but I suggest you Netty.io

You can create a kind of "snoop server" or custom server protocol for sending commands to your application and receive an answer about your request (for example if everything went OK or if you crushed on some error).

Comment: It looks like the right thing for a professional approach, which might just a little too sophisticated for my purposes. From your experience, is it hard to set it up?

Comment: it's not hard, but it's also not so easy. I mean the hardest thing is setting up you application to recive parameters change during execution flow and sandboxing all the current "processes" you are running during the edit.

The process sandboxing is needed otherwise you can compromise data integrity during the elaboration.